# Height of sidebar not filling out when wrapper expands due to wrapping content

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I'm trying to get a sidebar to be the full height of a container. 
This is a sketch of the problem:
[image]
The sidebar is centered, but as soon as the items in the row are wrapping (using flex-box), the sidebar does not scale with it in my current solution..

A simplistic version of the HTML would look something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="sidebar">
   </div>
   <div class="row">
       <div class="item">
       </div>
       <div class="item">
       </div>
       <div class="item">
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- This can be repeated multiple times -->
```

The scss I'm currently using is the following:

```
.wrapper {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   align-items: center;

   .sidebar {
       height: 100%;
       background-color: blue;
   }

   .row {
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: row;
       align-items: center;
       width: 100%;
       flex-wrap: wrap;

       .item {
          margin: 50px;
          width: 200px;
          height: 200px;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          text-align: center;
       }
   }
}
```

Any idea how i could resolve this occuring problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```css
.wrapper {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 0 0 150px; // simple sizing
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}

.item {
  margin: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="sidebar">
     <div>sidebar stuff</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems like the correct solution. Not sure how it works yet, but I'll figure that out, thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome! Nesting elements with flexbox can be quite tricky ;)

Your `.sidebar` is the child of a `display: flex` element and also a `display: flex` container for its own content. When you're building your layout with flexbox, always add content to the elements, because these rules tend to render differently with and without content. 

And sometimes you need to add one extra level of container within the tree to properly align your content (but that's not the case here with this basic layout).

Comment: Also, don't forget to test in every browser! For instance, Chrome flexbox defaults are not the same as Firefox defaults. You might need to define _every_ flexbox rule on _every_ element if you want your layout to be consistent in every browser: `flex-flow`, `flex-wrap`, `align-items`, `justify-content`, `align-content` and `flex-basis`. You should take advantage of SCSS mixins or create positioning-only classes ;)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, great help!

Comment: While this might answer the question, an answer saying _Here's how I would do it:_ + some code is quite useless, as it doesn't explain how and why it works. Also, _twekz_, in your comment, you say the `sidebar` is a flex container, which it is not (in OP's question), furthermore, you say different browsers has different defaults, which again is not true, though in some rare cases one or the other has a bug making them behave different. So for me this is a really bad answer with comments, actually state inaccurate facts. .. and a notification to you as well, @RinkStiekema

Comment: @LGSon I definitely agree on the fact that I focused on making the original code behave as expected, rather than explaining how flexbox works in this example. I thought it would be more useful to the OP than a spec-based type of answer, but you’re right, this doesn’t actually help anyone. My bad. I also anticipated the `.sidebar` as a container, which is not true in the original example, I agree.
However, I had several first-hand experiences of browser behaving differently (especially FF) when I didn’t declare most of the main flexbox rules and felt I should warn the OP about this.

Comment: If you correct my main point, to explain why/how your solution work, my down vote will go away. ... Also, to say _browser behaving differently (especially FF) when I didn’t declare most of the main flexbox rules_ sounds much better than _Chrome flexbox defaults are not the same as Firefox_ ... so also delete and re-post updated comments will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `align-self: stretch` on the `.sidebar`.

You have `align-items: center` being applied from the container. This centers all flex items.

You can use `align-self` on individual items to override the `align-items` coming from the parent.